# Magento static blocks. Remove wrapping <p>

Tags: magento, static, block

When i create static block magento wraps content with `<p>` tags. Which is very bad for DOM.
Is is possible to remove it somehow. I suppose it is some javascript but i don't know which one.

Comment: This was such an annoying feature. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Good question, didn't realise it could be disabled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Actually wrong on my earlier answer.*

**You need to turn the static block WYSIWYG editor off-by-default.**

Go to *System -> Configuration*, find General section on left hand side, click on *Content Management* and set *'Enable WYSIWYG Editor'* to *'Disable by default'* from list.

Then edit your static blocks carefully - use the WYSIWYG but check your HTML afterwards.

This behaviour is a standard feature of WYSIWYG editors, that is what they are for, the `<p>` tags are added in because they make nicely formatted text. Clearly this is not what you want if you add a static block containing just an image, so step out of the editor and check for `<p>` tags.

The WYSIWYG editor can also mangle variables entered into the static blocks, and it slows down admin page load times, therefore it is best to have it turned off by default.

Comment: And if the site admin needs to use the WYSIWYG?

Comment: Another way to handle this is wrap the offending widget in a <div>, this stops wysiwyg from adding a <p> tag, as long as the default div doesn't have a style or the content within doesn't explicitly depend on the DOM hierarchy, it shouldn't hurt the layout

Comment: @DWils this is a great hint. This will allow admins to use the wysiwyg but not unknowingly alter markup by making changes.

Answer (score 6):

A more user-friendly method would be to catch the `cms_page_render`-event, and use a regular expression to 'unwrap' the widget:

config:

```
<cms_page_render>
    <observers>
        <your_unique_handler>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Package_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>cmsPageRenderEvent</method>
        </your_unique_handler>
    </observers>
</cms_page_render>
```

observer:

```
public function cmsPageRenderEvent($observer)
{
    /* @var $page Mage_Cms_Model_Page*/
    $page = $observer->getPage();

    // Remove wrapping paragraphs around widgets:
    $content = $page->getContent();
    $content = preg_replace('/\<p\>{{(.*?)}}\<\/p\>/', '{{$1}}', $content);
    $page->setContent($content);
}
```

This would unwrap the widget out of their paragraphs prior to Magento's execution of them.

*Edit: the part between {{ and }} should be non-greedy.*

Comment: Good answer. +1 for following the api.

Comment: It's not a solution. Because sometimes <p> added automatically and sometimes it is just a normal content where <p> should be.

Answer (score 4):

edit js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js

```
var settings = {
        mode : (mode != undefined ? mode : 'none'),
        elements : this.id,
        theme : 'advanced',
        plugins : plugins,
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : magentoPlugins + 'magentowidget,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,forecolor,backcolor',
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : 'tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen',
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : 'insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        convert_urls : false,
        relative_urls : false,



        forced_root_block : '', /* <-- Add this setting */



        content_css: this.config.content_css,
        custom_popup_css: this.config.popup_css,
        magentowidget_url: this.config.widget_window_url,
        magentoPluginsOptions: magentoPluginsOptions,
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on where you are using your static blocks and what templates/theme you are using. Turn on the developer frontend hints, load your offending pages, identify the template file used and then pull out the `<p>` tabs from your phtml files.

A directly called static block does not put extra `<p>` tags in.