# Remove automatic P tag on static block

Tags: magento, tinymce

how do i remove automatic `<p> tag` on static block or static page, which js file(s) should i edit?

and also i don't want to disable the wysiwyg editor

already check on js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js 
still no idea where is it

```
var settings = {
            mode : (mode != undefined ? mode : 'none'),
            elements : this.id,
            theme : 'advanced',
            plugins : plugins,
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : magentoPlugins + 'magentowidget,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,forecolor,backcolor',
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : 'tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen',
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : 'insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,
            convert_urls : false,
            relative_urls : false,
            content_css: this.config.content_css,
            custom_popup_css: this.config.popup_css,
            magentowidget_url: this.config.widget_window_url,
            magentoPluginsOptions: magentoPluginsOptions,
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A wysiwyg editor needs a [forced_root_block](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aforced_root_block) in order to be able to use paragraph styles.
This forced_root_block is set to "p" by default.

Comment: you can set forced_root_block in your tinymce configuration like convert_urls. You might set this value to "div", but the problem is you will always have a root block element which you cannot get rid of becasue tinymce needs it.

Answer (score 3):

*Got to System > Configuration*

Select **Content Management** from left menu

Click **WYSIWYG Options** in right side

```
Set Enable WYSIWYG Editor value to Disabled by Default
```

Done

Comment: It does not solve the problem because when admin clicks on the Display WYSIWYG button, the <p> tags are added.

Answer (score 0):

edit js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js

```
var settings = {
        mode : (mode != undefined ? mode : 'none'),
        elements : this.id,
        theme : 'advanced',
        plugins : plugins,
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : magentoPlugins + 'magentowidget,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,forecolor,backcolor',
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : 'tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen',
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : 'insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        convert_urls : false,
        relative_urls : false,




        forced_root_block : '', /* <-- Add this setting */




        content_css: this.config.content_css,
        custom_popup_css: this.config.popup_css,
        magentowidget_url: this.config.widget_window_url,
        magentoPluginsOptions: magentoPluginsOptions,
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26396255/1136132